# Combine functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, slide

I try to combine some functions like this, but won´t work for me.

1. Panel will show for 1 second
2. Panel slide up
3. Slide Btn will go out of the viewport for a very short time
4. End: Slide Btn show on the right position

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fhy3E/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });

    $('#panel').html('This text will dissapear after 3 seconds.');
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#panel').animate({marginTop: '-450px'}, 500);
    },

    function aha() {
        $('.btn-slide').animate({marginTop:'-40px'}, 350);
        $('.btn-slide').animate({marginTop:'470px'}, 350);
    }), 1000)

});​
```

I need your help for this, please.

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function and an integer, not two functions. Also, you have a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: Can you explain how the button press fits in with your sequence of actions?

Answer (score 0):

bind a callback to the slideToggle function as a parameter.

```
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow",function(){
   ..do this when the slide has completed
});
```

Comment: binding callbacks for all of the things you mentioned should get the job done. Jquery supports them for all of their timed functions (such as animations).